# Terminal to open a popup window in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu-12.04

My c++ application needs to display a message via a popup window or an alternative. My application is running on Ubuntu 12.04 version. Can I program the application to open a Ubuntu type popup window? If possible, how?

Do I need to use gnome window or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to display a popup from a program that doesn't otherwise use a GUI, is probably just execute a command-line tool that does the work:

- to display a notification with no buttons, you can use *notify-send*

  ```
  system("/usr/bin/notify-send MessageSubject \"message body here\"");
  ```
- if you want buttons so the user can give a response, you could use the (much uglier) `xmessage`

  ```
  system("/usr/bin/xmessage")
  ```

(see each tool's manpage for all their options)

---

The alternative is really to use a full GUI framework (probably gtk+), and that's not typically a small change.

For example, you can use [libnotify](http://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/) directly (giving you the same basic capabilities as `notify-send`, but more control), but this also depends on [glib](http://developer-next.gnome.org/glib/unstable/). So, now you've added two external dependencies when you could just have run `system`.

Comment: Thanks `/usr/bin/xmessage  -center "Hello "`
`Is what I was need , I didn't want to install any extra libraries .

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the popup or any kind of window, you will have to reference either gtk+ or qt libraries in your application/program. gtk+ is advisable, since the ubuntu unity desktop is also based on gtk+ - this way your program will have lesser overhead and more performance gain while running on ubuntu. You can either use the default C library (libgtk2.0) or the gtkmm (libgtkmm) for C++.

You can get more information on how to refer these libraries, initialize gtk_main in your main() function, etc. at this place: http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php

Comment: From a normal terminal can i popup a qt window

Comment: Well, there is no such short-cut so that you can call a function like gtk.popup() or qt.popup(). In either case, you have to #include the libraries, initialize the windows using an initializer function like gtk_main(), and then call the actual window-rendering functions too. Whether you use qt or gtk is your choice, but in either case, there are no shortcuts!!

Comment: Also remember that you have to call the compiler with appropriate parameters for qt/gtk+ reference.

Comment: Is there any example on popup

Comment: can i get my c++ application to show a tray icon rather than pop window using c++

Comment: You can use one of these hello-world samples to code your dialog: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD. If you want to take some action on the button-click, however, then you need to understand signals and bind your function() to the button's click signal.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method to show tray-icon in gtk+ or qt. Since each desktop (Unity, Gnome KDE, etc..) has its own specific api/method for a system-tray, I don't think a standardization is possible on linux desktops.